# Layout help - relative or linear

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-linearlayout

I am creating a view that is meant to show an image on the left, a gridview on the right, and at the bottom of the screen I want to include a last screen, next screen, refresh, and home navigation buttons, ie:

image | gridview

imagebtn | imagebtn | imagebtn | imagebtn |

I have tried the below but have failed? Do I need a relative view (although I failed trying that as well) or what have I done wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/flowers"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">


        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="512dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainlogo"
        android:src="@drawable/talltree"
        android:gravity="top"
        />

        <GridView  
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"

        />

</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtona"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game1">
        </ImageButton>


        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonb"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gamelisttwo"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_refresh1">
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gohome"
        android:src="@drawable/gamelistone">
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtond"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gamelisttwo"
        android:src="@drawable/gamelisttwo" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/game2">
        </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

sorry for the formating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve your need by using both RelativeLayout and LinearLayout combine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button4" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first `LinearLayout` use this: `android:orientation="vertical"`

On the second `LinearLayout` use this: `android:orientation="horizontal"`

On the third `LinearLayout` use this: `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Comment: I actually fixed this little bit myself and changed "fill_parent"
 to wrap_content as the image buttons were getting pushed off the bottom of the screen. Now all I need to do is push the buttons down to the bottom of the screen rather than have them placed immediately after the first linear layout (image plus gridview). I might have to resort to relative layout after all.